# Wrap figure floats and Hebrew

Tags: graphics, floats, lyx, wrap, hebrew

I'm trying to create a wrap-float but even if there's nothing in the text it won't work.
I'm using LyX 2.0.5.1.
This is my MWE:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.0.5.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.5\columnwidth}%
\caption{}
\end{wrapfigure}%

שלום שלום

שלום שלום 

\end{document}
```

So even without any text it says

> \end{wrapfigure}
>                        %
>   I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
>   For example,`\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
>   this error. If you simply proceed now, the`\par' that
>   I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
>   argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
>   your `}' was spurious, just type`2' and it will go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need some text in a following paragraph of `wrapfigure` otherwise it won't work:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.5\columnwidth}%
\caption{}
\end{wrapfigure}%
Here we need some text so that this will be wrap around the image ...
```

My working example, needs `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{o}{0.5\columnwidth}%
\caption{}
\end{wrapfigure}
הבסיס לכל הצורות המתקדמות יותר של פיתוח עברית הוא השפה של ספרי הקודש של היהודים, התנ"ך עברית, שמקורו בכתבי העת הראשונה אלף לפנה"ס נוצרו ונערך ברציפות והתרחב ולבסוף עוגן על ידי זמנו של ישו. (הישנה) עברית ולכן לעתים קרובות מזוהה עם המונח "עברית מקראית", אפילו אם זה מוצדק בלשנות פחות היסטורית, כמו היסטוריה של ספרות: עברית העתיקה כמו השפה התנ"ך. בתנ"ך, השפה שְׂפַת כְּנַעַן הוא השפת כנען ("שפת כנען, ישעיהו 19:18") נקראת. לאחר חורבן בית המקדש בירושלים על ידי נבוכדנצר השני ב586 לפנה"ס והגלות בבל שלאחר מכן, השפה הרשמית המקומית של ארמי הגיעה למחזור בקרב היהודים, ולכן מעתה ואילך עברית להתחרות על עמדה ארמי ונרשמה הרבה השפעות של זה.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've updated my example this still doesn't work. I get the same error :\

Comment: The text must follow without an empty line and must be of a paragraph which can flow around the figure. The reason why some words are not enough.

Comment: even when I add multiply lines before and after I get the same error.

Comment: I cannot run your example in fact of a missing font. However, with replacing `babel` by `polyglossia` and using `xelatex` which makes more sense here, it works. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, it really looks like what I'm aiming for but I've tried setting it up in my document I keep getting an error: `\begin{document}                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox`). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.`

Comment: provide the lyx file for a download than it is easier to say what went wrong.

Comment: This is the test file: [link](http://goo.gl/cIickh) thanks!

Comment: http://perce.de/pub/test2.lyx is a running LyX file. You have to run it with `xelatex`

Comment: @SadStudent your .lyx file compiled successfully for me without any modification. Note that your .lyx file was not a minimal example. It was very long and included pictures. I had to replace the pictures (which I'm sure now don't scale properly). As for why it compiles for me and not for you I think it could be the LyX version (I am using LyX 2.1 beta2 and 2.0.7 development) or the TeX distribution (I am on Ubuntu and installed with [install-tl-ubuntu --hebrew](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu).

Comment: @scottkosty I'm truly sorry after Herbert's solution worked I've re-used the convenient file name "test" for other testing and poured some other file into it. It was never my intention to waste your time. I assure you  that at the time it only had a few words and a wrap-figure.

Comment: @SadStudent No apology necessary. Glad everything's working!

Comment: @SadStudent I took the link to the PDF down and deleted the files I downloaded (it sound like you might have left a private .lyx hanging around)

Comment: @scottkosty exactly right, I would also appreciate if you erased the public pdf link on your drrop-box too (I can still access it via the copied link) after all it's just wasting your space :)

Comment: @SadStudent Ah yes I forgot about the temporary PDF. It is now off Dropbox and off my computer.